How to animate multiple Tweens on Flutter?
So I am trying to achieve something similar to this Flutter example provided on the documentation
But I do not want it to be subject to a button, I want it to execute the animation by itself, and do it non-stop.
At least I need a Tween for the height, width and color, however, I am finding myself in a confusing situation on how to animate all of them, I kinda did it, but I know I'm missing a Animation property on my Widget, this is my result so far:

It is making jumps between the random values that are being generated.
This is my code:
class AnimatedSquare extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedSquare({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnimatedSquare> createState() => _AnimatedSquareState();
}

class _AnimatedSquareState extends State<AnimatedSquare>
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  late final AnimationController controller;
  late Tween<double> containerWidth;
  late Tween<double> containerHeight;
  late Tween<Color> containerColor;
  Random random = Random();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800)
    )
    ..forward()
    ..addListener(() {
      if(controller.isCompleted) {
        setNewValues();
        controller.forward();
      }
    });
    containerWidth = Tween<double>(
      begin: 250,
      end: random.nextInt(300).toDouble()
    );
    containerHeight = Tween<double>(
      begin: 250,
      end: random.nextInt(300).toDouble()
    );
    containerColor = Tween(
      begin: Colors.red,
      end: Color.fromRGBO(
        random.nextInt(255),
        random.nextInt(255),
        random.nextInt(255), 
        1
      )
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  void setNewValues() {
    containerWidth.begin = containerWidth.end;
    containerHeight.begin = containerHeight.end;
    containerColor.begin = containerColor.end;
    controller.reset();
    containerWidth.end = random.nextInt(300).toDouble();
    containerHeight.end = random.nextInt(300).toDouble();
    containerColor.end = Color.fromRGBO(
      random.nextInt(255),
      random.nextInt(255),
      random.nextInt(255),
      1
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Container(
          height: containerHeight.begin,
          width: containerWidth.begin,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: containerColor.begin
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Can anyone help me getting this issue resolved?, I couldn't find much info on the internet, used this question as my last resource

instead of those Tweens, AnimatedBuilder, AnimationController, listeners etc why dont you simply use AnimatedContainer (with onEnd: ... to repeat the animation)? more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html - the docs say: "Animated version of Container that gradually changes its values over a period of time.
The AnimatedContainer will automatically animate between the old and new values of properties when they change using the provided curve and duration. Properties that are null are not animated. Its child and descendants are not animated."

So basically I used part of @diegoveloper answer in order to solve my issue, I just added a Animation variable for each Tween, since I needed to get the end and begin properties into the setNewValues() method.
The final code:
class AnimatedSquare extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedSquare({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnimatedSquare> createState() => _AnimatedSquareState();
}

class _AnimatedSquareState extends State<AnimatedSquare>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late final AnimationController controller;
  late Tween<double> containerWidth;
  late Tween<double> containerHeight;
  late Tween<Color?> containerColor;
  late Animation<double> animContainerWidth;
  late Animation<double> animContainerHeight;
  late Animation<Color?> animContainerColor;
  Random random = Random();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800)
    )..addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        setNewValues();
        controller.forward(from: 0);
      }
    })..forward();

    containerWidth = Tween<double>(
      begin: 250,
      end: random.nextInt(300).toDouble()
    );

    containerHeight = Tween<double>(
      begin: 250,
      end: random.nextInt(300).toDouble()
    );

    containerColor = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.red,
      end: Color.fromRGBO(
        random.nextInt(255),
        random.nextInt(255),
        random.nextInt(255),
        1
      )
    );

    animContainerWidth = containerWidth.animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn
    ));
    animContainerHeight = containerHeight.animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn
    ));
    animContainerColor = containerColor.animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn
    ));

    super.initState();
  }

  void setNewValues() {
    containerWidth.begin = containerWidth.end;
    containerHeight.begin = containerHeight.end;
    containerColor.begin = containerColor.end;
    controller.reset();
    containerWidth.end = random.nextInt(300).toDouble();
    containerHeight.end = random.nextInt(300).toDouble();
    containerColor.end = Color.fromRGBO(
      random.nextInt(255),
      random.nextInt(255),
      random.nextInt(255),
      1
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: controller,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Container(
            height: animContainerHeight.value,
            width: animContainerWidth.value,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: animContainerColor.value,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


The result:


Thanks a lot!

You just need to use Animation with a Tween for a specific movement/action.
Also you need to listen the addStatusListener instead the animation listener.
This is your code fixed.
class _AnimatedSquareState extends State<AnimatedSquare>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController controller;
  late Animation<double> containerWidth;
  late Animation<double> containerHeight;
  late Animation<Color?> containerColor;
  Random random = Random();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800))
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          setNewValues();
          controller.forward(from: 0);
        }
      })
      ..forward();
    setNewValues();

    super.initState();
  }

  void setNewValues() {
    containerWidth =
        Tween<double>(begin: 250, end: random.nextInt(300).toDouble()).animate(
      controller,
    );
    containerHeight =
        Tween<double>(begin: 250, end: random.nextInt(300).toDouble()).animate(
      controller,
    );
    containerColor = ColorTween(
            begin: Colors.red,
            end: Color.fromRGBO(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255),
                random.nextInt(255), 1))
        .animate(
      controller,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: controller,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Container(
            height: containerHeight.value,
            width: containerWidth.value,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: containerColor.value),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}



The setNewValues method was used to animate from the last random values to new random values, without that it gets a weird jump from the very beggining, how can I get the end and begin properties if the variables are set as animations? it looks like you removed that part

Nevermind, just used part of your answer to solve that issue, it was helpful though, thanks!

You could up vote my answer if it was helpful

AnimatedContainer(
    height: containerHeight.begin,
    width: containerWidth.begin,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: containerColor.begin),
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);

use this as a return at AnimatedBuilder
